# Why .aar library can have res/ ，and not conflict to main res in android?

Tags: android, jar, aar

We all know that : in android, .jar file can not include resource ,because the resource's id will(maybe) conflict to project's resource's id.

But in .aar file, res/ is included, and not conflicts to the project's id.

Why .aar can have res. but jar can not ? Why can the aar file  resolve the id's conflict ?

Answer (score 0):

As i know,

There would be no conflict since same ids will be overwritten by bruteforce. So if you know the String id of a resource which uses a dependency, you can change it by declaring same string id.

Aar is a new build system that can include resources also for wider support of libraries. This is the why it can have resources. :D

Comment: Thanks for answer! Sorry for word "conflict",  "not be found" maybe better. Assume that we have a project contains layout . When we generate .jar file from the project, in class files, the layout id will be compiled as a static and can not be changed number, for example 0x7fxxxxx. Use this jar file, and copy layouts to another project, compile it, we may get the  id not be found error.  So when generate .aar file, the id  will not be static in class files ??

Comment: Think about we have an aar file of a project. (You can try to open it with by chaning its extenstion to .zip) It has classes.jar and resource files. If we copy only classes file it shouldnt be compile by itself. But i am not sure if we copy to resource to our project. We should give it a try :d